# How do I prove these compound functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Let $g:A \to B$ and $f:B \to C$ be two functions. Prove that:
>
> a. If both $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one then so is $f \circ g$.
>
> b. If $f \circ g$ is one-to-one then $g$ must be one-to-one.

I'm not sure how to prove these cases. I understand that one-to-one means that all $x$ in the pre-image of $y$ equal a unique value. I know how to prove it with numbers but this question is asking me to prove it with compound propositions. I never did that before and I have no idea where to start. Also how can I prove/disprove that $f \circ g$ is one-to-one if both $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Defn: $f: A \rightarrow B$ is one-to-one iff $\forall x,y \in A, f(x)=f(y) \implies x=y$

Let $x,y \in A \ni f(g(x))=f(g(y))$. It remains to show that $x=y$.
Since $f$ is one-to-one, $g(x)=g(y)$ by definition.
Since $G$ is one-to-one, $x=y$.
Thus $f \circ g$ is one-to-one.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it now!

Answer (score 1):

Take $a_1,a_2\in A$.

a. Suppose $f(g(a_1))=f(g(a_2))$: you want to prove that $a_1=a_2$. By hypothesis, $f$ is one-to-one, thus what can you say about $g(a_1)$ and $g(a_2)$?

b. Suppose $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$. Then $f(g(a_1))=f(g(a_2))$, but $f\circ g$ is one to one, so...

Answer (score 1):

Recall what one-to-one means: A function $f:B\to C$ is *one-to-one* if whenever $b,c\in B$ satisfy $f(b)=f(c)$, we necessarily have $b=c$.

This kind of proof generally follows the pattern:

> "Suppose $b,c\in B$ are such that $f(b)=f(c)$
>
> [... Here you do your mathematical magic ...]
>
> And then we conclude that $b=c$. This proves that $f$ is one-to-one".

Let's try and solve the first one with this: Suppose both $f$ and $g$ are one-to-one. In order to show that $f\circ g:A\to C$ is one-to-one, take $a,b\in A$ for which $f\circ g(a)=f\circ g(b)$. This means that $f(g(a))=f(g(b))$.

To be a little clearer, let's write $x=g(a)$ and $y=g(b)$. THe above equality writes $f(x)=f(y)$. This is pointing out, clearly, for us to use the fact (hypothesis) that $f$ is one-to-one. Indeed, this implies $x=y$, that is, $g(a)=g(b)$. Now **this** is pointing us to use the fact (hypothesis) that $g$ is one-to-one, and indeed this implies $a=b$.

Therefore, from $f\circ g(a)=f\circ g(b)$, we concluded that $a=b$. This means that $f\circ g$ is one-to-one.

For the second exercise, you follow a similar partter:

> "Suppose $f\circ g$ is one-to-one. Take $a,b\in A$ with $g(a)=g(b)$.
>
> [... work a little bit ...]
>
> So we conclude that $a=b$. This means that $g$ is one-to-one."

I'll leave the details for the second one to you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I makes sense now.